# How to put Mask in textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Application is asp.net MVC.

I want to put a textbox for date using mask.

Please refer This [ajax controls](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) for getting exact idea.

Comment: Masked edit boxes for dates??  Of course its up to you but how about doing something more user friendly like a proper date picker.  Masked edits are fine for coded values like serial numbers or national insurance codes where the format is a useful part of the validation.  For dates however as long as it is date what does it matter what actual format is used to enter it?

Comment: I am also using datetime picker using JavaScript, But you know, CLIENT'S REQUIREMENT !

Comment: Well, if you have a large form for data entry and only one date field it's a real PITA to have to lift your hand from the keyboard and grab the mouse to click through date picker. Especially if date is something like a birthday, i.e. 1-100 years back. Navigating 100 years in dropdown is a major pain even if you use the mouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) does a very good job.